# T POSE CLOTHING PROBLEM

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

[image]I am trying to apply a T posed mesh Top to a somewhat different T posed static mesh. It is a mesh for Sims 3 and I am saying that because even though I have managed to make the cloth hug the model without any deformations by adding an armature, in the end in order for the armature to bone/auto weight on the clothing part, altered some things on the mesh which is problematic for the texture. I don't know where this data of which parts are mirrored and which aren't is, and it resulted in the texture to follow a mirror path throughout the whole mesh and not exclude the individual parts (f.e. big armlet on the L side). So I am trying to find another way to make the top hug the model. Also I have to add that I don't know after many errors and tries and managed to bind the armature with the top because I had the Heat weight bone problem. I tried deleting doubles but that just drops the quality of the top a lot. And doing the seperate loose parts gives me around 900 seperated parts which is also not good. Can someone help me? thank you.

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Yeah of course
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5731" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5731/)